# how can i pass constructor values when deploying through truffle?

Tags: constructor, smartcontracts, web3js, truffle, ganache

How can I deploy a smart contract with constructor predefined parameters values, I am using truffle, ganache!!

```
constructor (uint256 _targetAmount, uint256 _setDeadline) public {
        totalAmount = _targetAmount;
        deadline = block.timestamp + _setDeadline;
        minDepositAmount = 1 ether;
        manager = payable(msg.sender);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the constructor params after the first argument of [deployer.deploy()](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations/#deployerdeploycontract-args-options).

```
deployer.deploy(MyContract, targetAmount, setDeadline);
```